# Update MultiIndex-DataFrame with a DataFrame which MultiIndex is a subset of the first

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two panda DataFrames `x` and `y` each with a MultiIndex. The MultiIndex of `y` is a subset of `x`. I would like to update fields in `x` using values of `y`:

```
x.index.names
Out[]: FrozenList(['cohort', 'id', 'design', 'date'])

y.index.names
Out[]: FrozenList(['cohort', 'id'])
```

Ho can I do that?

---

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
```

The DataFrame `x`:

```
# sets of different measurements on different subjects on different
# dates.

df = pd.read_pickle('protocol.pkl')

df.set_index(
        keys=['cohort', 'id', 'design', 'date'],
        inplace=True,
        verify_integrity=True,
        drop=True)

df.head()
Out[]:
                             valid  epi
cohort id design date
FOOBAR 1  FOO    2014-04-22   True    3
       2  BAR    2014-04-24   True    3
       2  BAR    2014-04-25   True    3
       4  FOO    2014-04-25   True    3
       4  BAR    2014-05-05   True    3

df.shape
Out[]: (714, 2)
```

The DataFrame `y`:

```
# subjects to exclude from the study

up = pd.read_pickle('outlying.pkl')

up.set_index(keys=['cohort', 'id', 'design'],
        inplace=True,
        verify_integrity=True,
        drop=True)

up.head()
Out[]:
                     valid
cohort id  design
FOOBAR 1   BAR       False
       2   BAR       False
       12  BAR       False
       22  FOO       False
       28  FOO       False

up.head()
Out[]: (14, 1)
```

The result of the update should be:

```
df.head()
Out[]:
                             valid  epi
cohort id design date
FOOBAR 1  FOO    2014-04-22   True    3
       2  BAR    2014-04-24   False   3
       2  BAR    2014-04-25   False   3
       4  FOO    2014-04-25   True    3
       4  BAR    2014-05-05   True    3
```

I was hoping

```
df.update(up)
```

does the trick, as the index of up is a "subset" of df, but it has no effect on df.

Comment: Can you add data sample with exected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try reindex with `Multiindex`, but get:

> TypeError: Join on level between two MultiIndex objects is ambiguous

So possible solution is [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace `NaN`s:

```
df = (df.reset_index().join(up, on=['cohort','id','design'], lsuffix='_')
        .assign(valid=lambda x: x.valid.fillna(x.valid_))
        .drop('valid_', axis=1)
        .set_index(['cohort','id','design', 'date'])
       )
print (df)
                             epi  valid
cohort id design date                  
FOOBAR 1  FOO    2014-04-22    3   True
       2  BAR    2014-04-24    3  False
                 2014-04-25    3  False
       4  FOO    2014-04-25    3   True
          BAR    2014-05-05    3   True
```